# HTML Agility Pack Find Server controls

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am doing a small c# application to search asp:TextBox controls in aspx pages.

I would like to know how can I search for all TextBox controls in aspx pages using HTML Agility Pack.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubjectName"  runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Find out what the rendered HTML for a control looks like, and you're one step closer.

Comment: @J.Steen: he wants to find the controls in an aspx page not in the rendered html

Comment: @TimSchmelter Benefit of the doubt, sure. Still not researched in the least. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: true, but that are his words: _"how can I search for all TextBox controls in aspx pages"_ (not in a html file)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'll skip the discussion on why I assumed what I assumed - yes. That's how you'd parse the question in its very literal sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("asp:TextBox")`. Note that the `Where` is not really needed but you can use it if you need all server controls not only `TextBox`:

```
var allTxt = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("asp:TextBox")
    .Where(txt => txt.GetAttributeValue("runat", "").Equals("server", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This presumes that you have an aspx text file which you want to analyze and not the rendered html which doesnt contain server controls.